# drag and drop multiple select item

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, primeng, multi-select

I need to handle a drag drop multiselect item. In details I must multiselect some item in a part and drag in another part to print the multiselect values. I want use `primeng` and I follow the guide on its site. The problem is the drag&drop prime ng is for single select item but I need Multiple select item. Anyone can help me to understand how can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `metaKeySelection` is set to `true` only .You just need to press `Ctrl` key and select multiple items